# Utilizar webcam na web com maior resolução possível

Tags: javascript, html5, css3, aplicação-web

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação simples para capturar fotos através de uma web cam, a parte de capturar a foto e salvar ta funcionando tranquilamente, no entanto estou com problemas de resolução. 
Quando utilizo um software instalado no pc, a imagem fica de ótima qualidade, quando vou para o browser essa qualidade toda some.

Gostaria de saber se:

Os browsers atualmente tem esse limite de resolução mesmo?

Qualquer ajuda, sugestão será bem vinda.

Comment: Bom, quem sabe o software desktop faça uma otimização na imagem, aplicando filtros. Mas como você está capturando a imagem da web cam e jogando no browser?

Comment: @ChristianFelipe to utilizando HTML5 e javascript basicamente

Comment: document.getElementById("capturarFoto").addEventListener("click", function()       
 
     context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 640, 480);
     var img = document.getElementById("canvas").toDataURL("image/jpeg");
  document.getElementById("imagemCapturada").src = img;
 
});